# Import/export only new data by ID

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There are two databases A and B. Each has the same tables T, even the same records ID. But table A has been updated with new data. How pass only new data from A to B by id (skip existing id). Using import/export wizard and t-sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple.. Create `unique index` on `ID` of `B` table and set `ignore duplicate values=True` Make sure that your `ID` has `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: thanks, created index on PK and set ignore duplicate values = Yes. Import/export wizard self skips existing records by id

Comment: Welcome..Happy Coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can export all records from A then import it into a staging table in B. Then you use query to insert into Table B by selecting the staging table WHERE ID not exists in (TABLE B).